# Split view spinners/recycleview

Tags: android

I have to update some code and i need a hint to accomplish this.
Currenty the view is split in 2 layouts(header,body)
Header has an imageview and a couple of textviews .
Body has a recycle view.
Now, I need to remove the imageview and insert some spinners which will take some parameters to bring data form tha database and show it on the recycleview.
I belive i have to replace the view holder extend recycle view  to insert a spinner, could anyone point me the structure of java file to accomplish the task?

Answer (score 0):

If your imageview is in the header part and you want to replace the imageview with the spinner then you will not need to extend the recycler view.

Steps:

1. Add spinners in the header view.
2. Add some event that will detect if the selection was made.
3. Bring data from database based on the parameters from the spinners.
4. Show that data in the recycler view.

No need to extend recyclerview to add spinners.